# code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"

Tags: django

im deployed my app Django in Heroku but, the application not works, it show me that error, this is my repo https://github.com/zlcosio21/MoralGamesWeb the code of the application, the files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGSh0.png)

I tried changing the procfile and it doesn't work either.